# How can I read IBM jit dump file

Tags: java, jit

I want to look into the jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp file.
Which is generated by IBM JVM 1.8 when it's crashing. Does anyone know how to read the dmp file?

I tried to use jextract to analyze it, but it complaints as following:

```
/opt/ibm/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/jextract /tmp/jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp -v
Loading dump file...
Error. Dump type not recognised, file: /tmp/jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp
```

When trying to open jitdump file via MAT+DTFJ, here is the error message:

```
Error opening heap dump 'jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp'. Check the error log for further details.
Unable to read dump C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\core_files\opt\ibm\apm\playback\selenium\jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp metafile null in DTFJ format DTFJ-J9 (java.io.IOException)
Unable to read dump C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\core_files\opt\ibm\apm\playback\selenium\jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp metafile null in DTFJ format DTFJ-J9
No Image sources were found for C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\core_files\opt\ibm\apm\playback\selenium\jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp (java.io.IOException)
No Image sources were found for C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\core_files\opt\ibm\apm\playback\selenium\jitdump.20160505.165247.149.0004.dmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is intended for IBM internal analysis only, the contents of the JIT dump files are not useful to anyone without an in depth understanding of the IBM JDK's JIT compiler internals. The existence of JIT dump file(s) does not imply that a JIT problem was encountered, the file was generated to collect data during a JVM crash so that if the crash is determined to be a JIT problem that IBM would stand a better chance of fixing the problem without having to ask for more data by recreating the problem several times.

Comment: Accept this answer as at least I understand that I cannot understand the content of jitdump without the knowledge of IBM JIT compiler.

Comment: Yes, the other point being made in that answer was that a jitdump could be produced regardless of whether the actual problem was related to the JIT or not. i.e. the jitdump is just one of the dumps that the IBM JDK creates in order to be able to do post mortem analysis. Does the crash output say that it crashed in the JIT module or in JIT generated code ?

Comment: Yes. It's crashed in JIT module. 1XHEXCPMODULE  Module: /opt/ibm/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libj9jit28.so.  Dump event "gpf" received.  Java Heap size looks good, and no dead locks found in javacore file. This why I was trying to look into jitdump

Comment: I think there are probably a couple of options if you would like IBM to help with the problem you are having : 1) If you are working on a product that has a formal support agreement with IBM, you should just open a PMR and it will be routed to the JIT compiler team to look at. 2) If you do not have any formal support agreement, IBM would still try to help if you uploaded the dump files to ftp://ftp.ecurep.ibm.com/toibm and let me know, I will contact the IBM JIT compiler support team on your behalf and have them look at the dumps soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) with [IBM DTFJ plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/mat.html).

Comment: I think MAT+DTFJ can be able to open heap dump file, like phd. But cannot open jitdump file.